# Phonegap ChildBrowser plugin: Disable/Hide URL in Locationbar, but NOT back/forward/exit buttons

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

is there a way to hide or disable the URL field in the locationbar? In my case the device is a tablet run as a kiosk browser, so only one URL is allowed.

I fixed this by changing the code in the ChildBrowser.java to

```
private void navigate(String url) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
    if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
        this.webview.loadUrl("http://" + url);
    }
    this.webview.loadUrl("http://www.my-only-allowed-site.example.org");
    this.webview.requestFocus();
}
```

This works well, but is not nice. You can still see the URL.   I´d like to have any of this possible solutions:
1) completely hide the URL field
2) hide the softkeyboard when clicking on the URL field
3) set the URL fonts color to black

Any idea?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you modify the source code for the plugin, you can hide the url field and close button by modifying the source code for the plugin and just comment out the following line:

```
toolbar.addView(back);       //shows the back button
toolbar.addView(forward);    //shows the forward button
//toolbar.addView(edittext); //shows the URL - comment this line out to hide the URL
toolbar.addView(close);      //shows the close button
```

**Edit**: oops, I just saw from your comment that you figured this out in the same way!

Comment: Any idea for ios platform what is to be modify in plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Phonegap but I'm assuming you're using a standard Android `WebView`?

If you're seeing a URL bar then it usually means that the default system browser is being invoked to handle the loading of the page. To prevent this set a `WebViewClient` as follows...

```
this.webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` method is called by the host application to see if it should override the loading by using Activity Manager to find a suitable app (usually the stock browser app). Returning `false` means the `WebView` instance wants to handle its own URL loading and you won't see a URL bar at all.

EDIT: If that fixes it but also looses the navigation buttons then I suggest you maintain your own history collection and provide your own buttons for back/forward/exit.

Comment: thanks for the hint.  I just removed the line `                    toolbar.addView(edittext);    ` from the Childbrowser.java and it worked.